# Is there a more efficient tool than iterrows() in this situation?

Tags: python, performance, pandas, dataframe

Okay so, here's the thing.  I'm working with a lot of pandas data frames and arrays.  Often times, I need to pair up a value from one frame with a value from another, ideally combining the information into one frame in the end.

Say I'm looking at image files.  There's a set of information specific to each file.  Sometimes there's certain types of image files that share the same kind of information.  Simple example:

```
FILEPATH,    TYPE,   COLOR,   VALUE_I,<br>
/img2.jpg,    A,    'green',   0.6294<br>
/img45.jpg,   B,    'green',   0.1846<br>
/img87.jpg,   A,    'blue',    34.78<br>
```

Often, this information is indexed out by type/color/value etc and fed into some other function that gives me another important output, let's say VALUE_II.  But I can't concatenate it directly onto the original dataframe because the indices won't match, either because of the nature of the output or because I only fed part of the frame.

Or another situation: I learn that images of a certain TYPE have a specific value attached to them, so I make a dictionary of types and their value.  Again, this column doesn't exist, so in this case I would use iterrows() to march down the frame, see if the type matches a specific key, and if it does append it to an array.  Then in the end, I convert that array to a dataframe and concatenate it onto the original.

Here's the worse offender.  With up to 1800 rows in each frame, it takes FOREVER.:

```
newColumn = []

for index, row in originalDataframe.iterrows():
    for indx, rw in otherDataframe.iterrows():
        if row['filename'] in rw['filepath']:
            newColumn.append([rw['VALUE_I'],rw['VALUE_II'], rw['VALUE_III']])

newColumn = pd.DataFrame(newColumn, columns = ['VALUE_I', 'VALUE_II', 'VALUE_III'])
originalDataframe = pd.concat([originalDataframe, newColumn], axis=1)
```

Solutions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you can split filename from `otherDataframe["filepath"]`, you can then just compare for equality with orinalDataframe's filename without need to check `in`. After that you can simplify calculation with [pandas.DataFrame.join](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html), which for each filename in originalDataframe will find the same filename in otherDataframe and add all other columns from it.

```
import os

otherDataframe["filename"] = otherDataframe["filepath"].map(os.path.basename)
joinedDataframe = originalDataframe.join(otherDataframe.set_index("filename"), on="filename")
```

If there are columns with the same name in originalDataframe and otherDataframe you should set lsuffix or rsuffix.

Answer (score 0):

focusing on the second half of your question, as that's what you provided code for.  Your program is checking every row of df1 against every row in df2, yielding potentially 1800 *1800, or 3240000 possible combinations.  If there is only one possible match for each row then adding 'break' in will help some, but is not ideal.

`newColumn.append([rw['VALUE_I'],rw['VALUE_II'], rw['VALUE_III']])
break`

if the structure of you data allows it, i would try something like:

```
ref = {}
for i, path in enumerate(otherDataframe['filepath']):
   *_, file = path.split('\\')
   ref[file] = i

originalDataframe['VALUE_I'] = None
originalDataframe['VALUE_II'] = None
originalDataframe['VALUE_III'] = None

for i, file in enumerate(originalDataframe['filename']):
    try:
        j = ref[file]
        originalDataframe.loc[i, 'VALUE_I'] = otherDataframe.loc[j, 'VALUE_I']
        originalDataframe.loc[i, 'VALUE_II'] = otherDataframe.loc[j, 'VALUE_II']
        originalDataframe.loc[i, 'VALUE_III'] = otherDataframe.loc[j, 'VALUE_III']
    except:
        pass
```

Here we we iterate through the paths in otherDataframe (I assume they follow a pattern of C:\asdf\asdf\file), split the path on \ to pull out file, and then construct a dictionary of files to row numbers.  Next we initialize the 3 columns in originalDataframe that you want to write to.

Lastly we iterate through the files in originalDataframe, check to see if that file exists in our dictionary of files in otherDataframe (done inside a try to catch errors), and pull the row number (out of the dictionary) which we then use to write the values from other to original.

Side note, you describe you paths as being in the vein of 'C:/asd/fdg/img2.jpg', in which case you should use:

```
*_, file = path.split('/')
```